# Shell Script to update the contents of a folder - 2

Tags: shell

I wrote this piece of code this morning.
The idea is, a text file (`new.txt`) has the details about the directory structure and the files in the directory.
Read `new.txt`, create the same directory structure at a destination directory (here it is `/tmp`), copy the source files to the corresponding destination directory.

#### Script

```
clear    
DEST_DIR=/tmp    
for file in 'cat new.txt'    
do    
   mkdir -p $file    
   touch $file    
   echo 'ls -ltr $file'    
   cp -rf $file $DEST_DIR    
   find . -name $file -type f    
   cp $file $DEST_DIR    
done
```

#### Contents of new.txt

```
Test/test1/test1.txt    
Test/test2/test2.txt    
Test/test3/test3.txt    
Test/test4/test4.txt
```

The issue is, it executes the code, creates the directory structure, but instead of creating it at the end, it creates directories named `test1.txt`, `test2.txt`, etc. I have no idea why this is happening.

---

Another question: For Turbo C, C++, there is an option to check the execution flow? Is there something available in Unix, Perl and shell scripting to check the execution flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script creates these directories because you tell it to on the line `mkdir -p $file`. You have to extract the directory path from you filename. The standard command for this is `dirname`:

```
dir=`dirname "$file"`
mkdir -p -- "$dir"
```

To check the execution flow is to add `set -x` at the top of your script. This will cause all lines that are executed to be printed to `stderr` with "+ " in front of it.

Comment: Thank you very much Schot. Thats helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to try something like [rsync](http://www.samba.org/rsync/)